# Undecorate Chromium Browser in KDE4?

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde4

Chromium browser in KDE4 looks bad , unlike other WM , a border showed up on top , how can i remove them , and let chromium display its own buttons (e.g close / max / minimize) ?

Thanks !

Comment: Preferences>Personal Stuff>Use Compact system titlebar and Borders?

Comment: Did that solve the problem warl0ck ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I lost my access to openid for months .. just back

Comment: welcome back =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution was suggested in the comments

> Preferences>Personal Stuff>Use Compact system titlebar and Borders

If that is not what you want, I suggest you file a  bug report / feature request.